# Python: parsing a config file to dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, lambda

I'm trying to parse a config file for a fortran model to a python dictionary. The config file is basically a number of lines containing arrays or strings e.g.:

```
0, 400, 700, 0.02, 488, 0.00026, 1, 5.3
rootname
filename
0,1,0,0,0,1
2,1,0,2,3
4,4
0.0, 0.0, 2980.9579870417047, 0.01,
...
...
...
```

The line number and array index tell me to which variable the value belongs. So I decided to make a dictionary where the keys describe the variable and the values the indices of where the variable can be found in the config file e.g.:

```
parameters = {"var1": [3,2],
              "var2": [4,1],
              "var3": [4,2]}
```

So if I would read the config file as a list with `.read()` I could create a dictionary with the parameter values as follows:

```
def get_parameters(config_list):
    dict_out = {}
    for key, value in parameters.items():
        dict_out[key] = config_list[value[0]][value[1]]
    return dict_out
```

The problem however is that the config file has a dynamic number of lines depending on the number of components in the model. Fortunately, the number of components (another variable) is also specified in the config file. Let assume the first 7 lines are static; after the 7th line the number of lines are depended on the number of components. The number of components `ncomp` is 3 (specified on the 5th line and the 5th entry in the array ([4][4]). Now i want to retrieve variable `var4` on line 7+`ncomp`+1 and array index `2`. How do I go about this in an elegant way?

I thought about adding lambda expressions to my `parameter` dictionary:

```
parameters = {"var1": [3,2],
              "var2": [4,1],
              "var3": [4,2],
              "ncomp": [4,4],
              "var4": [lambda ncomp: ncomp+7,2]}
```

But this would mean that I first have to retrieve `ncomp` and then evaluate the lambda function to get the indices. With the indices I could then retrieve the values of `var4`. It sounds doable but I feel like there might me a more elegant way to solve this problem. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps.

First all parameters but `var4`:

```
parameters = {"var1": [3,2],
              "var2": [4,1],
              "var3": [4,2],
              "ncomp": [4,4]}

out = get_parameters(config_list)
```

Now `var4`:

```
out["var4"] = config_list[int(out['ncomp']) + 7, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:
Since you have well defined dependencies, you will have to set up the loop accordingly while fetching parameters in the dictionary.There's no alternative as I see it.
You do not have to bother about defining your dependent parameters in the `'parameters'` dictionary since many params are dynamically read and obtained.
So, only define the independent ones in `'parameters'`
Suppose there are 2 dependency defining params like `"ncomp"` and `"ncomp2"`.
 And there are 2 dependent params for each, say var10, var11, var12 and var13.
While var14 and var15 are dependent on both `"ncomp"` and `"ncomp2"`.
You'll now group them into the respective batches as follows.

```
def get_parameters(config_list):
    dict_out = {}
    for key, value in parameters.items():
        if key == "ncomp":  # for all the params dependent on number of components.
            dict_out[key] = config_list[value[0]][value[1]]
            ncomp_val = dict_out[key] # we now have the value of ncomp in out dictionary available for all its dependent parameters.

            dict_out["var10"] = config_lit[ncomp_val*2 +1][4]
            dict_out["var11"] = config_lit[ncomp_val*3 +1][2]

         elif key == "ncomp2":  # for all the params dependent on number of components.
            dict_out[key] = config_list[value[0]][value[1]]
            ncomp1_val = dict_out[key]

            dict_out["var12"] = config_lit[ncomp1_val*2 -1][3]
            dict_out["var13"] = config_lit[ncomp1_val*3 +3][4]

         elif "ncomp" in dict_out and "ncomp2" in dict_out and "var14" not in dict_out:  # for the multi-dependency params, dependent on ncomp and ncomp2.
            ncomp_val = dict_out["ncomp"]
            ncomp1_val = dict_out["ncomp1"]

            dict_out["var14"] = config_lit[ncomp_val*2 + ncomp1_val -1][3]
            dict_out["var15"] = config_lit[ncomp1_val*3 + ncomp1_val*2 +3][4]

        else:  # for all other independent params.
            dict_out[key] = config_list[value[0]][value[1]]

    return dict_out
```

**Original Response**:
I agree with @Mike Muller's answer, however, you can avoid breaking it into 2 steps.
While retrieving the parameters into your dictionary, you can easily check for the "ncomp" key and proceed.
Let's work with your assumption of 7 static lines, and by then, you will have gotten your "ncomp" value into your dictionary.
You can now capture all your dependent parameters based on this value as follows.

```
def get_parameters(config_list):
    dict_out = {}
    for key, value in parameters.items():
        if "ncomp" in dict_out:  # for all the params dependent on number of components.
            dict_out[key] = [dict_out["ncomp"]+7+1 , 2]
        else:  # for all other independent params.
            dict_out[key] = config_list[value[0]][value[1]]
    return dict_out
```

Comment: the problem is that i have a list of 'dependent' parameters that i want to retrieve. All these parameters are written to different lines (e.g. `ncomp` * 2 + 1, or `ncomp`*3 +1 and 'ncomp` * 2+ 'ncomp2' + 1 (i.e. dependent on two parameters). There is quiet a number of these variables with different dependencies. I thought it would be nice to capture all these different dependencies in a dictionary (the parameter dictionary in my post). How can I accommodate for this in a clean and elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

@murphy1310 thanks for your thorough answer. However I am not a fan of hardcoding all the indices in the function itself. I would rather keep all the indices of the variables in a (single) dictionary so i can keep the function "clean". I came up with the following:

```
# config_list is a 2D list of parameter values and strings
config_list = [[...],
               [...],
               [...]]

# dictionary containing indices of where variables can be found in config_list
parameters = {
              # independent variables
              "var1": [3,2],
              "var2": [4,1],
              "var3": [4,2],
              "ncomp": [4,4],
              # dependent variables
              "var4": lambda ncomp: [ncomp+1, 1],
              "var5": lambda ncomp: [ncomp*2+1, 1]}

def get_parameters(dictin, dictout = {}):
    dictin_copy = dictin.copy()
    for key, value in dictin_copy.items():
        if not callable(value) and not dictout.get(key):
            dictout[key] = config_list[value[0]][value[1]]

    ncomp = dictout["ncomp"]
    for key, value in dictin_copy.items():
        if callable(value):
            dictin_copy[key] = value(ncomp)
            get_parameters(dictin_copy, dictout)
    return dictout

# now get parameters from config_list
new_dict = get_parameters(parameters)
```

I'm wondering what you guys think of this approach...

Comment: tomato tomahto.. btw, could you show us how `'differently'` you would handle the multi-dependency parameters that you had mentioned in your comment? It would end up looking similar to my response, since you too are extracting and holding value of ncomp.in a temp variable, so what's the big advantage with placing the unused `'values'` of the dependent variables.